# onMenuItemSelected is not called

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

Since `onOptionsItemSelected` i want to migrate to `MenuProvider`.

After implementing interface and adding provider onMenuItemSelected wont be called when clicking on Menuitem. Only onCreateMenu is called.

It all works with the old API but the new way just does not recognize any clicks

Does anyone know what may be missing?

Code:

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.view.MenuProvider;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Editor extends Fragment implements MenuProvider {

    private AppCompatEditText properties;
    private String getFilePath;
    private Ad ad;
    private String line;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requireActivity().addMenuProvider(this);
        FileTools.deselectAllFiles();
        FileTools.setFileOperationPending(false);
        requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editpmyml, container, false);
        ad = new Ad(requireActivity());
        ad.init();
        requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.card).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getFilePath = Fileexplorer.mkPath.toString();
        properties = view.findViewById(R.id.cont);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        File name = new File(Fileexplorer.mkPath.toString() + "/" + ResAdapter.fileName);
        String filename = name.getName();

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            savedInstanceState.clear();
        }

        requireActivity().setTitle(filename);

        try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getFilePath), 1024)){

            while ((this.line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(this.line + "\n");

                if (line.trim().startsWith("#")) {
                    try {
                        spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.GREEN)), 0, this.line.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        requireActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> getProperties().append(spannableStringBuilder));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        getProperties().append(this.line + "\n");
                    }
                } else {
                    requireActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> getProperties().append(this.line + "\n"));
                }
            }

        }  catch (Exception ignored) {}

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    public static void dirSub(){
        String nameToRemove = "/"+ new File(Fileexplorer.mkPath.toString()).getName();
        Fileexplorer.mkPath.delete(Fileexplorer.mkPath.lastIndexOf("/"),Fileexplorer.mkPath.lastIndexOf("/") +nameToRemove.length());
        

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.sv) {
            writeFile(Objects.requireNonNull(properties.getText()).toString(), getFilePath);
        }else{
            dirSub();
        }

        return true;
    }
    private void writeFile(String content,String path) {
        try(FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(path)){
            ad.showAd();
            fileWriter.write(content);
            fileWriter.flush();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.saved), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dirSub();
            requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).setReorderingAllowed(true).replace(R.id.mainFragment,new Fileexplorer()).commit();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
        menu.clear();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.save, menu);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.card).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.card).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onStop();
    }

    private EditText getProperties() {
        return this.properties;
    }



}
```

Comment: You used in fragment so, Override onCreate method inside setHasOptionMenu(true);

Comment: setHasOptionsMenu is deprecated and i cannot override onCreate in that method it does not make sense

Comment: Does your activity override `onOptionsItemSelected`? Please include that code as well.

Answer (score 5):

Like the comment by @ianhanniballake. Maybe you have something like below code in the Activity.

```
 override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
     when (menuItem.itemId) {
         android.R.id.home -> finish()
     }
     return true // this line
 }
```

or

```
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> finish()
    }
    return true  // this line
}
```

`return true` means you handled every menu item and not to perform other menu handling.

Replacing `true` with `false` in the Activity works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this dependency to your app level *build.gradle* file. This will call **onOptionsItemSelected** method, that's how its worked for me.

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.2'
```

Comment: I have added the same but same issue.